# Rendering HTML Partial block in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partials

I am trying to insert a custom header (held in a database) on my master page. The custom header changes on a user by user basis.

I'm slightly confused on how to attach a controller to a partial (if I even can do this). What I'm hoping to accomplish is to render a block of code from a specific controller called with some events.

```
    public ActionResult GetHeader(Guid clientID)
    {
        string szHeader = GetTheme(ThemeType.Portal, JoloTheme.ThemeArea.Header, clientID);
        return Content(szHeader, "text/html");
    }
```

Is the controller I have created, but I'm not sure how to get this onto a subsection of a page I am currently writing (not in the same Controller).

Apologies if this is completely nonsense here, still learning MVC I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Html.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423.aspx) helper in your _Layout.cshtml. I think you should use a Nullable Guid as a parameter because you won't be able to provide a valid clientID always.

```
public ActionResult GetHeader(Guid? clientID)
{
    string szHeader = GetTheme(ThemeType.Portal, JoloTheme.ThemeArea.Header, clientID);
    return Content(szHeader, "text/html");
}
```

Here's how you should call Html.Action helper in your _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("GetHeader", 
             "SomeController",
             new { clientID = IsLoggedIn ? ClientID : (Guid?)null } )
```

Comment: Thanks, luckily the ClientID is always guaranteed (has a default value if null). But didn't realise the Action could render on page, I thought it was just for linking. I've still got a lot of reading to do :D